# Swift iOS -How to Switch / Toggle between two UIWindows and make either the keyWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I created an additional UIWindow that will get presented on top of the main window. The user presses a button and it transitions over the main window. The user can minimize the additional window and it will sit above the tabBar like it the picture below. They can enlarge it to cover the main window or dismiss it and it gets destroyed. It works fine.

I also created a custom action sheet that launches from the bottom of the screen. If the additional window completely covers the main window and the action sheet is launched, it will launch perfectly inside the additional window. If the additional window isn't on the screen it launches perfectly inside the main window.

**The problem is if the additional window is minimized on screen and I want to launch the action sheet from the main window, the action sheet launches inside the additional window instead, it cannot distinguish between the two.** I opened up the 3D visualizer and it showed that the main window was `off` and the additional window was `on`.

How can I distinguish between both windows when displaying the custom action sheet?

Btw if both windows are present and the action sheet is launched from the main window I hide the additional window. I also looked at other answers and they said to use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.addSubview` which I'm already doing.

CustomActionSheet Class:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var deltaY: CGFloat!
let height: CGFloat = 200 // 4 cells x 50 pts each

func displayActionSheet(){

     if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

         // collectionView initialized...
         window.addSubview(collectionView)

         deltaY = window.frame.height - height

         collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {

             self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: deltaY, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
         }
      }
}
```

MainView Class:

```
@IBAction func mainWindowActionSheetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

      let customActionSheet = CustomActionSheet()
      customActionSheet.displayActionSheet()
}
```

AdditionalWindow Class:

```
let myVC = MyController()
var nav: UINavigationController?
var window: UIWindow!
var maximized = true

override init() {
    super.init()

    window = UIWindow()
    window.backgroundColor = .clear
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
    nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
    window.rootViewController = nav
    window?.isHidden = false
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }

 func maximizeOrMinimizeWindow() {

    if maximized {
         // show this full screen
    } else {
        // show this window minimized like in the picture
    }
 }
```

AnotherController Class that has the button that also launches the action sheet:

```
@IBAction func additionalWindowActionSheetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

      let customActionSheet = CustomActionSheet()
      customActionSheet.displayActionSheet()
}
```

[image: window in window]

[image: main window]

[image: additional window]

Comment: Well, you are using the key window. Why dont you just store references to the windows instead? Or dont make the secondary window a key window?

Comment: @Sulthan I thought about that as an option but since the code that creates the additional window is in an entirely different class I would have to use a singleton. I thought there could possible be an easier way if I could use the window's on and off properties (which I cannot find)

Comment: If the window is minimized then you should probably also make it not to be the key window. You are the one controlling which window is the key window. Also, you can just iterate over `UIApplication.shared.windows`, check the class of the window and whether it is minimized or not. You are already using singletons.

Comment: the minimized window when maximized takes over the entire view including the tabBar, basically it sits in front of everything, that's why I made it another uiwindow.

Comment: I am not asking why you have made it a window. I am asking why you have made it a *key* window.

Comment: How else can I present the additional window where it takes over the entire screen but can also get minimized to the height in the picture ? The problem with a regular modal presentation is it's part of the original window's hierarchy, it gets presented and dismissed normally

Comment: But there is no reason why the window should stay "key" once it is minimized. You should make the other window to be the key window then.

Comment: I forgot I can use the .makeKeyAndVisible(), and remove it from there. I'll split them up and try it now.

Comment: Thanks, you was correct! I'll post the code in a few minutes  :) enjoy your day!!!

Comment: By the way, you don't need to set `window.isHidden = false` if you are calling `makeKeyAndVisible` after that. That `andVisible` part sets `isHidden` to `false` :)

Comment: lol, as I removed makeKeyWindow I realized that. Thanks 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The summarize the advice in comments.

The problem is that the action sheet is always shown from the *key* window but the additional window remains *key* window even when minimized.

The obvious solution is to make the main window the key window when the additional one is being minimized. See [UIWindow.makeKey()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621610-makekey) or [UIWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621601-makekeyandvisible).

Since `UIApplication.shared.windows` are ordered by window level (the back one first), you can always reach the main window using `UIApplication.shared.windows.first`.

Therefore

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKey()
```

will make the main window the *key* window and the minimized window will stop being the *key* window.

Comment: quick question, how do i call .resignKey() so I can toggle the key on and off when maximized and minimized. Apple says don't call it directly

Comment: @LanceSamaria `resignKey` is not something you can call. It's a method you override in `UIWindow` subclass to know when the window has finished being `key` window. The only way how to make a window the key window is to call any of the methods above. For example you could `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKey()`. Note that `UIApplication.shared.windows` is ordered by the window level.

Comment: See your idea 100% worked but the new problem I ran into was since the additional window is no longer a key window, when it’s full screen the custom action sheet launches on the window behind it (the main window). I need to toggle between the 2 states. eg. if maximized { window.first?.makeKey } else { window.resignKey() }. I know I can’t call resignKey() directly but I need something to call to tell it to remove itself as the key window.

Comment: @LanceSamaria As I said `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKey()` should do the trick. You just have to tell the other window to become "key".

Comment: wow it worked! I'm going to upvote the answer too. You know I've looked around and haven't found anyone who explained how to toggle between both with windows and not to use resignKey(). This was excellent advice help. If you have the time you should add some code to your sewer to help other people out.

Comment: Here's the code I used based on your idea: if maximized { window.first?.makeKey } else { UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKey() // called when minimized }. This works

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code breakdown to @Sulthan 's accepted answer. Read the comments in the code for an explanation.

```
let myVC = MyController()
var nav: UINavigationController?
var window: UIWindow!
var maximized = true

override init() {
    super.init()

    window = UIWindow()
    window.backgroundColor = .clear
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
    nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
    window.rootViewController = nav!
    window?.isHidden = false
     // window?.makeKeyAndVisible() // don't call this because it doesn't need to be the keyWindow as of yet. The window?.isHidden property above this makes the window visible
 }

 func maximizeOrMinimizeWindow() {

    if maximized {

        window.first?.makeKey // when the additional window is maximized make it the keyWindow
    } else {

        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKey() // when the additional window is minimized set the main window back as the key window
    }
 }
```

It should also be stated then when the additional window is removed from the superview or destroyed make sure to set the main window back as the keyWindow using `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKey()`