# Swift iOS -Second UIWindow sometimes animates from wrong coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uiwindow

I have a button inside a vc. When I press that button I launch second UIWindow from the bottom right hand corner of the screen. For some reason when it launches it sometimes launches from the lower right hand corner like it's supposed to but other times it launches from the top left hand corner or the middle of the screen. I tried calling `window.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation but that actually messed the entire layout up.

**Why doesn't it consistently start from the lower right hand corner of the screen?**

The second window is starting from a small 10x10 w/h frame in the lower right hand corner of the screen and then animating to the x/y 0,0 position to fill the entire screen.

```
@IBAction fileprivate func launchSecondWindowButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let mainWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

    let myVC = MyController()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    // starts from a small 10x10 w/h frame in the lower right hand corner of the screen
    let startingFrame = CGRect(x: mainWindow.frame.width - 10, y: mainWindow.frame.height - 10, width: 10, height: 10)

    let secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: startingFrame)
    secondWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
    secondWindow.rootViewController = nav
    secondWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        secondWindow.frame = mainWindow.frame // this is the entire screen
        // secondWindow.layoutIfNeeded() didn't help
    }
}
```

Comment: But why do you need a window to be added? is there any specific reason why you trying in that way?

Comment: yes there is. here is another q/a i had with some pics: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51105924/4833705

Comment: so you are basically trying picture in picture sort of feature right?